# One class calling another class's method (nstimer) that fails to call selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one view which, when loaded instantiates a method in another class which uses an nstimer. The nstimer then calls another method to populate an array which will be used to populate a table view. However, the nstimer selector is returning 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[inbox repliesMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x102a199d8''. Out of my depth on this one. I've checked the name of the selector and it is correct and the first view does call the timer, but after the 6 seconds the crash occurs. Thanks

first view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     thankYouMessage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Thank You %@ for your message. Your message has reached Hubble. We will reply shortly.", self.name3];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.messageSent = @"yes";

    NSLog(@"Call timer method");
    [inbox timerForOtherMethods];
}
```

second view (inbox)

+(void)timerForOtherMethods {

```
    NSLog(@"populate array timer");
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:6 target:self selector:@selector(repliesMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
NSLog(@" add timer");
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

}

```
-(NSMutableArray *)repliesMethod {
    NSLog(@"Create replies array");
    NSMutableArray *replies = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Create dictionary reply");
    NSDictionary *reply = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"From:", @"The Sorting Office", @"Subject:", @"Message from Hubble", nil];

    NSLog(@"add reply to replies array");
    [replies addObject:reply];

    NSLog(@"Add reply to all replies");
    self.allReplies = replies;

    NSLog(@"%@", allReplies);

    return replies;

}
```

Comment: Why is your `timerForOtherMethods` declared static?

Comment: I made it a class method so I could call it from the first class. If I made it an instance method, create an instance of the second class in view did load of the first class, and call it for that, would that start the timer also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timerForOtherMethods` is a class method.  When you say `self` in a class method it means the class rather than an instance of the class.  That means your timer is trying to invoke `+repliesMethod` instead of `-repliesMethod`.

Comment: Am I right in thinking I need to change timer target? Or change it to an instance method?

Comment: Well, you need to be consistent between which things are done for the class as a whole and which for a single instance of the class.  I'm sort of confused about the purpose of `inbox` and why `repliesMethod` has a non-void return value.  (A firing timer isn't going to make any use of a returned array.)

Comment: Its a play app. The first view controller represents a sent message. The second is an inbox which is a tableview populated by an array of replies (one reply created each time a message is sent). What I'm trying to achieve is that when the sent screen is loaded it triggers the timer to delay the reply being created (the six seconds will be longer  for the final app). After the time has passed, a reply is created, a notification (yet to be added) will be fired and the inbox will show a new reply. Any comments are greatly appreciated; this is the first app I'm attempting away from convention.

Comment: This may be getting a bit off topic for your question but....  What if you create a class that represents your data model?  It would be a Singleton and handle everything about messages and replies except actually displaying them.  The display would happen when a view controller gets the notification you mentioned.  I feel that having timers and data creation embedded in view controllers causes difficult complications.

Comment: By changing it to an instance method all works. However: 1) for some reason the timer is called twice? and 2) when I click for the inbox I get the following crash  - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "sNw-y2-Ync-view-C47-sF-vF4" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'   The view is a tableview, and I've set it's class to inbox. Any ideas. Thank you for all you time on this :)

Comment: You should be able to debug the "called twice" problem with breakpoints to see where the calls are coming from.  The "didn't get a UITableView" thing is quite specific; it thinks you have a  `UITableViewController` in your storyboard with a `view` property which is not linked to a `UITableView` object.  If you are **absolutely sure** that isn't true, then all I can suggest is cleaning the project, maybe deleting derived data, and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
+(void)timerForOtherMethods
```

to:

```
-(void)timerForOtherMethods
```

Comment: If I do this, how's best to then call the timer from the first class - would it would by creating an instance of the second class and calling it from that?

Comment: Sounds like a good option.  I would have the newly instantly class create and manage the timer such that if the instance goes away it will delete the timer.